# Adding bootstrap's glyphicons to the input search field of datatable

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I have successfully incorporated datatables with bootstrap(thanks to datatable's excellent documentation!). I would now like to use bootstrap's glyphicons for the  input search field . To do this, I need to place an icon with `<i class="icon-search"></i>`. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

things i have tried is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table').dataTable( {
    sDom: '<"icon-search"r><"H"lf>t<"F"ip>',
    oLanguage: {sSearch: ""},
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bSort": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false } );
} );
```

but this places the icon  as such not inside the input field.

I want to wrap the input field as :

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="inputIcon">Search : </label>
  <div class="controls">
   <div class="input-prepend">
   <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
   <input class="span2" id="inputIcon" type="text">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give us a working example? I'm guessing you need to play with the datatables CSS.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/C4ZY3/3/ .. see this i want dataTables search input box to be of this form.

Comment: or like this http://jsfiddle.net/chne9/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add "oLanguage" to your javascript like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datatable').dataTable({
        "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "oLanguage": { "sSearch": '<i class="icon-search"></i>' }
    });
} );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that very simple answer :-)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem for bootstrap 3.
The solution I found to add boostrap 3 `input-group` and `input-group-addon` to the datatable lenght menu or search input for example is to add this code into the dataTable plugin options :

```
    $('#yourTableId').dataTable({   
        'language': {
            search: '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>',
            searchPlaceholder: 'Your placeholder...',
            lengthMenu: '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span></span>_MENU_</div>',
            ...
        }
    });
```

A `</div>` is missing for the search input but the navigator auto-detect this and complete it for you. I didn't find out how to add the closing `</div>`, using the plugin options.

All the option to custom dataTable are available here : http://www.datatables.net/reference/option/

I hope it will save time and energy for some of you ;)

Comment: This works great, but for some reason the search glyphicon has some space between the search input field even though the lengthMenu works perfectly. Any ideas as to why this is?

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for!  I spent hours trying to use svg images in the background etc. and instead this came out perfectly with 99592349 times less hassle.  Good day sir.